# Lon/Lat coordinates for imported shapefile are displaying in the thousands

Tags: qgis

I'm having some trouble with my Italian regions shapefile.

Here I have imported my shapefile into QGIS but as you can see the Coordinate field at the bottom is showing very high numbers, and not the longitude and latitude that I am expecting. How can I see the correct longitude and latitude?

The file is downloaded from here http://www.istat.it/it/archivio/124086

[image]

Comment: Its reprojected (on the fly - that is the OTF bit) into EPSG:900913, which is the spherical Mercator projection. The units are in metres (not degrees). If you want it in degrees, switch your project to EPSG:4326 or some other SRS that uses degrees. See http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_projections.html for more details.

Comment: You should post this as an answer @BradHards :)

Comment: I've been scratching my head over this for ages. Thank you very much @BradHards

Answer (score 5):

Using `Project -> Project Properties -> General`, you can select the coordinate display between degrees and project CRS units (meters in most cases).

This way you can switch to degrees without any reprojection of the project or layer.